# Why does swift say that when I don't import the cocoa framework, there are no member functions of the String?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, string, cocoa

If you run the following function in vs code, you will get a compilation error that the addingPercentEncoding function does not exist, but if you import the cocoa framework, it will run normally. What's the difference between the two?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `import Foundation`. Importing Cocoa will import Foundation as a dependency

Comment: "What's the difference between the two?" Did you not expect importing something to give you more APIs to use?

Answer (score 0):

That method - `.addingPercentageEncoding` is part of the `NSString` bridging, which adds the behavior of `NSString` to the swift String implementation. This functionality is introduced by importing `Foundation`. The import of `Cocoa` also imports `Foundation`.

The `.urlQueryAllowed` is a part of `NSCharacterSet`, which gets imported into the swift class `CharacterSet` by bridging also.

The bridging here introduces a lot of functionality that doesn't need to be reimplemented in the base class.

Comment: It’s not really a string extension, it’s part of `NSString` which is automatically bridged to the Swift `String` type (converting between the two).

Comment: The majority of the NSString bridging is done by Foundation. I'll update the answer to be a little more clear on this point

Comment: My comment wasn’t very clear either. I meant that the  NSString bridging is part of Foundation and that the percentage encoding is really a method on NSString, not String.

Answer (score 0):

The addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:) function is a part of the Foundation framework in Swift, which provides a set of common data types and APIs for working with strings, dates, URLs, and more. The Cocoa framework, on the other hand, is a higher-level framework that builds on top of Foundation, and provides additional functionality for developing macOS and iOS applications.

When you import Cocoa, you are also importing Foundation, because Cocoa depends on Foundation. This is why you are able to use the addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:) function without any compilation errors.